# How can I filter rows which contains less than 3 whitespaces in a column? (R)

Tags: r

I have tried multiple reg exp for resolving this problem but none of them is correct.

I have a data frame like this:

```
    df <- data.frame("Name" = c("Antonio Garcia Fernandez", "Mark Wahlberg", "Juan Antonio Frontera Márquez", "Jose Maria Alvarez Sainz"))
    print(df)
```

And I would like to get the result as a new data frame in which the names would be those which have less than 3 whitespaces between characters:

| Name |
| --- |
| Antonio Garcia Fernandez |
| Mark Wahlberg |

Can someone give me the reg exp which can filters for those values which contains less than 3 whitespaces?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `stringr::str_count` is probably your friend 

https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_count.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   filter(str_count(Name, '\\w+') <=3)
                      Name
1 Antonio Garcia Fernandez
2            Mark Wahlberg
```

Answer (score 2):

Some base R options:

```
subset(
  df,
  nchar(gsub("[^ ]", "", Name)) < 3
)
```

or

```
subset(
  df,
  lengths(regmatches(Name,gregexpr(" ",Name)))< 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
subset(df, nchar(gsub(pattern = "\\S", "", df$Name)) < 3)
                      Name
1 Antonio Garcia Fernandez
2            Mark Wahlberg
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Quixotic22 mentioned you can use `str_count` to count the number of words and keep the rows which has less than equal to 3 words in them.

```
df[stringr::str_count(df$Name, '\\w+') <= 3 , , drop = FALSE]

#                      Name
#1 Antonio Garcia Fernandez
#2            Mark Wahlberg
```